# how can I open a model inside components function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I try this method to open a modal but it not working :

```
const Item = ({ title, details,  }) =>{ 
const [detModel, setdetModal]= useState(false)
return(
<View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={setdetModal(true)} >
<View style={styles.firstitem} >
  <Text style={styles.title} >{title}</Text>
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
 //  this is the modal who i want to open it if user press in the touchableOpacity
<Modal visible={detModel}>
<Ionicons name="ios-arrow-round-back" size={42} style={styles.colsemodal} color="black" onPress= 
{setdetModal(false)}/>
<Text>{title}</Text>
<Text>{details}</Text>
</Modal>
</View>
 )} ;
```

but i got this error:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

how can I open this modal  with the state method.

Comment: You probably meant to pass `onPress` a function. `onPress={() => setdetModal(false)}`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't understand what do you means can you please explain more ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={setdetModal(true)} >
```

Here, you are currently calling the `setdetModal` method in when JSX is rendered causing re-renders and hence the loop.

Instead, you should pass an arrow function.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setdetModal(true)} >
```

Same goes for all other `onPress` handlers.

Comment: Or any handler at all.

Comment: @Abdrahmanbadou you’re welcome, but also thank nipuna777 by upvoting this answer.